# Where command for MYSQLnd install must be used?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp, mysqlnd

I must use this command to install MySQLnd on OS X. But I can't understand where exactly must I use it?

```
./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
[other options]
```

Comment: Have you read the section about [how to compile PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php)?

Comment: Have you tried using MacPorts or HomeBrew to install MySQLnd? I think they would provide support for this, and either would be easier than recompiling PHP.

Comment: @Machavity I am using MAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are flags for the configure step when [compiling and installing PHP from source](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php). You cannot do this after the fact, you need to entirely reinstall PHP from scratch for this. Depending on how exactly you installed PHP in the first place, there may be simpler options than doing this; for example by installing an extra package using the package manager you used to install PHP before.

Comment: As far as I know, php is like preinstalled in OS X, right? Also I am using MAMP, so I didn't set up anything

Comment: I wouldn't really touch the OS X preinstalled PHP at all, especially if you're trying to customise it. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a fantastic way to have a semi-customised and customisable PHP installation. MAMP is a ready-made package, and while you can customise it if you know what you're doing, it may still not be as flexible as other options. Check if MAMP explicitly has a solution for using mysqlnd.